# How can i retrieve the public ip of fargate task(instance running on fargate) using boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-ecs

I want to create a dynamic DNS where a lambda function will trigger to create a fargate task using the particular task definition on a particular service.After creating the task,the lambda function will create record set against the public ip of the fargate task in route53 on a specific hosted zone .Now the issue is how can i retrieve public ip of the fargate task using boto3?
If it is wrong way to do that then what will be the correct or standard?